# Javascript opt.prop is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically building a select list using Javascript. It works but I ran into trouble when trying to disable some options. The code is below. The `opt.prop` line generates the error `opt.prop is not a function`. I also tried `attr('disabled', 'disabled')` and got `opt.attr` is not a function.

```
var selSubCat = document.getElementById('selectedSubCategory');
for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = categories[i]['name'] + ' (' + categories[i]['q_count'] + ' items)';
    opt.value = categories[i]['id'];
    if (categories[i]['q_count'] < 1 )
        opt.prop('disabled', true);
    selSubCat.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using `jquery` at all, but `DOM methods`. Then you need to change:

```
opt.prop('disabled', true);
```

by

```
opt.setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
opt.disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on w3c at the **< option >  element**, since that is actually what you are creating with **document.createElement('option');** 
-http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

If you take a look at the **listed attributes** you will notice **there is no "prop" attribute or method**, and you have not created a custom attribute either called prop. That's what the browser console is trying to tell you when it says "opt.prop is not a function".

What I believe *you are actually trying to do is set its* **"disabled"** attribute, which as shown in the **w3c documentation does exist** to "true" which will **however also cause you a problem** since the documentation shows that **the "disabled" attribute only accepts one value, "disabled".**

In order to set an attribute, simply use your element instance, in your case "opt" and invoke it's setAttribute method, for example, **opt.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");**

If you are attempting to do something else entirely such as create a custom html data attribute, which is part of the HTML5 spec, then please clarify your intent in your question and I'd be happy to help :D